# How to Pass variables between two Javascript files in mocha chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have created two test files in mocha chai . I want to access variable that has been in file1 to be accessd in file 2 so that i can use them in file 2

**FILE1.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');
const _ = require('lodash');
const customerData = require('./data/customer.json');

let me,accessToken;

const invalidAccessToken = 'e0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Imh0dHBzOmFjYmZsY2kybmVmcWtheXl6ZHM0In0.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.g0cdX7P34VemXT8nO5uaqKrKmSjc8caXWwS6T3Mo7Cb';


before(async() => {
    //API call 
    expect(response).to.have.property('data');
    expect(response.data).to.have.property('access-token');
    accessToken = (response.data['access-token']) ? response.data['access-token'] : '';  
});
```

I want to access this accessToken in FILE2.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to keep all helper variables in a separate file:

```
// variables.js
module.exports = {
  invalidAccessToken: 'e0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Imh0dHBzOmFjYmZsY2kybmVmcWtheXl6ZHM0In0.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.g0cdX7P34VemXT8nO5uaqKrKmSjc8caXWwS6T3Mo7Cb'
};
```

And then you could access it in any file:

```
const variables = require('./variables');

console.log(variables.invalidAccessToken);

// ...
```